# How to enable TLS 1.2 support in an Xamarin Android application C#

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, tls1.2, azure-api-apps

I'm developing a Xamarin project. With the help of C# code, I need to access the azure API for my project. It produces the following error 'Could not create a secure channel'. So I'm using the following line of code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But also after adding the line, it throws the same error.

But when I compile the same code from the console application it produces the result. Is there any problem with my code or with my mobile device?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=macos

Comment: I can't find that path... project options->android options->advanced.    Where is that in the project???

Comment: That will be in your Xamarin.Android application project.

Comment: There only I can't find the option.

Comment: Windows: `Project Options > Android Options, then click the Advanced Options button.`  Mac: `Project Options > Build > Android Build settings and click on the General tab.`

Comment: Can not find project options? RIGHT-CLICK on the project in the solution explorer and choose the Options item is one way to get there....

Comment: This is the **CORRECT ANSWER**. Post this as a answer. It will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the link for this issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=macos

**Windows: Project Options > Android Options, then click the Advanced Options button.
Mac: Project Options > Build > Android Build settings and click on the General tab.**

This is not "**my answer**". Somebody mentioned this in the above comment section.